# Is it possible to install 2 Android applications when running a Test on Amazon Device Farm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

In order for my tests to run successfully on Amazon Device Farm I need to install an OpenVPN app before hand. Is it possible to programatically install an app before the test run?

Answer (score 0):

We do have the ability to install additional apps and media files to the device before the actual app we're testing get installed.

When scheduling a run using the web console, we should see an option for uploading the additional app on the 'specify device state' page.

However I'm not sure how we would interact with that additional app.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#getting-started-create-run => step 10

To do this programmatically, we would create the uploads using the [creat-upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/create-upload.html) cli command and then upload the file using:

curl -T /path/to/file "s3presignedurl"

Then when using the [schedule-run](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/schedule-run.html) command we can specify that we want to us this as extra data from the configuration option.

Hope that helps

James

Comment: Thanks for the help, James. Do you have a way to control the additional app with an automation script? We use Cucumber/Calabash in Java

Comment: That I'm not sure about with cucumber and java whilst using device farm. Device Farm doesn't support cucumber java right now unless you purchase private devices. 

However in Calabash Ruby there are backdoors we can use to maybe so something like that. 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/working-with/backdoors/